# How to retrieve uploaded image from a MYSQL database

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, image

I am designing a website where when the user uploads the image it returns the 10 prominent colors present in the image. I am able to upload the image into mysql database but I've troubles retrieving
the image from the database and passing it into my main color finding program

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image
up_im=""
cap=""
# Create your views here.
def starttest(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        global up_im,cap
        con=sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="****", database='test_pro',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',buffered=True)
        cursor=con.cursor()
        pos=request.POST
        for key,value in pos.items():
            if key=='IMAGE':
                up_im=value
            if key=="caption":
                cap=value
        c="insert into userdata values('{}','{}')".format(up_im,cap)
        cursor.execute(c)
        retr="select IMAGE from userdata where caption= '{}'".format(cap)
        cursor.execute(retr)
        data=cursor.fetchone()
        uploaded_image=data[0][0]
        binary_data=base64.b64decode(uploaded_image)
        show_image=Image.open(io.BytesIO(binary_data))
        show_image.show()
        con.commit()
```

I have connected mysql python and html using django
This is the error I get (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqOUK.png)
[this is the line of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw2d1.png)
And I followed this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/retrieve-image-and-file-stored-as-a-blob-from-mysql-table-using-python/

Comment: Why do you use raw queries and not the Django ORM?

Comment: I get attempted relative import with no known parent package error so I tried a different approach.

Comment: @Thurannivek: but the ORM is part of Django itself...

Comment: I stored the images as models and then uploaded into a static media folder but when I try to execute the command from .models import modelname I get the error attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Likely because where you are importing them, that is the root package. You need to follow the app structure where the root python directory has directories, one per app, and each app has a `models.py`.

Comment: Let's say the app's name is x and models.py is inside x even when I import it as from x.models import modelname I still get the same error

Comment: then likely you don't run the process through `manage,py`, or `manage.py` is not located in the root directory. So at the level of `manage.py` you put the app *directories*.

Comment: Yes the import commands are on views.py and all the directories are placed properly